# CSS Position:fixed not working

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I created this .css file for my page:

```
#content-box, #header-box, #menu-box, #footer-box
{
    background-color:#084B8A;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#content-box
{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    min-height:205px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    margin:1px;
    padding:5px;
}

#menu-box
{
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    height:205px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    margin:1px;
    padding:5px;
}

#footer-box
{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0.5px 5px;
    text-align:right;
}

#header-box
{
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0.5px 5px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

And I want to #menu-box to move when I scroll down/up the page but is not working.
Here is the arrangement of page:

```
#header-box
---------------------------------------
         |#
         |c
#menu-box|o
         |n
         |t
         |e
         |n
         |t
         |-
         |b
         |o
         |x
---------------------------------------
                            #footer-box
```

In every div(#header-box, #menu-box, #content_box, #footer-box) I add information( in #menu-box I add a css vertical drop-down menu).

EDIT: Here is my HTML code, I think the problem is with the table tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="ro">
<head>
<title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="100%"><tr><td><div id='header-box'>Bine ai venit
</div></td></tr></table>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr><td style="width:200px; height:205px;"><div id='menu-box'><?php include("nav.php"); ?></div></td>
<td><div id='content-box'>
<?php // content ?>
</div></td></tr></table>
<table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td><div id='footer-box'>Creat de ...</div></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

(normal the border are setted to 0 but now, because I setted to 1 I can't see my #menu-box)

@Andrew: I know I need a long page, and I have a one where in the #content-box I listed tables.

Comment: A [testcase](http://cssdeck.com/labs) with HTML (and the CSS too) code will help!

Comment: I added the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cXmhS/

It seems to work. You need to have a larger amount of content for the menu to move with the scroll bar.

To make it work better i changed your `min-height:1005px;`

Comment: Add a margin-left to your content-box to avoid the menu overlapping, and it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Even though I see similar answer, I have tried to create my own example. And to me, it is good if you would set width for you `#menu-box` as there is no way to float left. Even defining a margin wouldn't help, if the menu-box will have automatic width.

My solution will be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6sg3v/

With defining `width:` for `#menu-box` and appropriate `margin-left:` for `#content-box`

Comment: so you want to say my problem is with the table tags?